# Google service account for googols calendar api calls

Tags: google-cloud-platform, asp.net-core-webapi, google-calendar-api

I have an asp.net core web api which I want to pull the google calendar events via the .net sdk. I have a service account created and I’ve downloaded the json key. In addition I’ve shared my personal gmail calendar with this service account via google calendar ui. It’s unclear based off of various posts if the service account can access the calendar api. If it can I have seen zero examples online of how to do this task.

My reason for using a service account is because I had planned to use okta as my idk as they offer an embedded login widget so the user doesn’t leave my site and I can completely customize my login screen.

Answer (score 0):

re: service account, usually, there are two steps:

1. Creating it in your Google Developer Console
2. Activating domain wide access in your Admin console

Walk through [this article](https://docs.aurinko.io/authentication/setting-up-g-suite-service-account) to see if you've set up your account correctly.

And if Google auth is all you need for your users you may even use [Aurinko](https://www.aurinko.io/blog/using-aurinko-to-store-access-tokens/) for logins while getting Calendar API access at the same time. It also simplifies working with Calendar API using a service account.